# How to "delete" items from unorder list

Tags: javascript

I am doing a simple project of "to-do list". now I am facing a problem, that is **deleted** items from **unorder list**.i can not delete an **items** from the list.

here is my **HTML** code

here is default three list item here

```
 <!-- *** InputField and Add Button *** -->
    <div>
        <input type="text", placeholder="Write Something Here">
        <button class="addButton">Add New Item</button>
    </div>

    <!-- *** List Items *** -->
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                hello
                <button>Delete</button>
                <button>Edit</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                hello2
                <button>Delete</button>
                <button>Edit</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                hello3
                <button>Delete</button>
                <button>Edit</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>



    <script src="./index.js"></script>
```

**I can add new items in the ul list. also, I can delete the first item of the list by that code but I can't delete more item from the list.**

here is my **js** code

```
// Input field and Add Button
let input = document.querySelector('input')
let addBtn = document.querySelector('.addButton')

// List Items
let ul = document.querySelector('ul')
let li = document.querySelectorAll('li')

// List Button
let deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button')[1]
let editBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button')[2]


// Add New Item
let addNewItem = function () {
    // Create New Item
    let li = document.createElement('li')
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button')
    let editBtn = document.createElement('button')

    // Button Need to modify
    deleteBtn.innerText = 'Delete'
    editBtn.innerText = 'Edit'

    // Appending buttons to LI
    li.innerText = input.value
    li.appendChild(deleteBtn)
    li.appendChild(editBtn)

    // Append LI to UL
    ul.appendChild(li)

    //Clear The Input Field
    input.value = ''

}

// Set Add button to add new item
addBtn.addEventListener('click', addNewItem)


**i tried to delete item from ul list by that code**
// Delete new or old Items From list 
let deleteItem = function () {

    let li = this.parentNode
    ul.removeChild(li)

}

deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', deleteItem)
```

**I want to delete new and old items when I click on the delete button. it will automatically remove from the list which one I pressed**

here is my **output** [plese visit here]
https://jsfiddle.net/noyon_ahmed/cfb5juk3/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete more than the first item, because

```
let deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button')[1]
```

points to the second button-element in the document.

Giving your delete buttons a class - "delete" for example - and rewriting the above to

```
let deleteBtn = [...document.getElementsByClassName('delete')]
```

and then changing the attachment of the click-handler to

```
deleteBtn.forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', deleteItem))
```

should make your code work.

If you want that behavior for newly added items, you need to attach the handler when you create the corresponding delete-button in your addNewItem function, like:

```
    // Appending buttons to LI
    li.innerText = input.value
    deleteBtn.onclick = deleteItem
    li.appendChild(deleteBtn)
    li.appendChild(editBtn)
```

Comment: ok, but the ul list will be increasing by user..so I get the new item in the list every time.so how can i get the new item list and delete that one

Comment: Attach the delete-handler whenever you add a new delete button, like so `deleteBtn.onclick = deleteItem`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes.

Make sure you're adding the event listener to all the buttons at the start:

```
// List Button
let deleteBtns = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// ...

for (var i = 0;i<deleteBtns.length;i++) {
    deleteBtns[i].addEventListener('click', deleteItem)
}
```

When you add a new item, be sure to add the event listener:

```
// Append LI to UL
ul.appendChild(li)

//Clear The Input Field
input.value = '';

// add this: 
deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update your code accordingly

```
<ul>
   <li>
       hello
       <button class="delete">Delete</button>
       <button>Edit</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        hello2
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
        <button>Edit</button>
     </li>
     <li>
          hello3
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
        <button>Edit</button>
      </li>
 </ul>
let deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button.delete')


deleteBtn.forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', deleteItem))
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kqjhp2oy/38/)

Answer (score 0):

Just a general tip, I would not select on tag names.  Doing so may end up interfering with new HTML added in the future, like say, a list of navigation items.  Give each list item a specific class name, like `todoListItem` and select on that instead with `querySelectorAll('.todoListItem')`.  I also think this will be easier if you start with an empty list and populate it based on data.  In other words run everything through your addNewItem function.  Then, if you add an event listener to the delete button within this scope, it should apply to only the current item.

```js
const addNewItem = text => {

    //... trimmed

    li.textContent = text

    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click',
      () => li.remove())

   // ... trimmed
}
```